# 304 not modified with jquery UI in rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

edI m working on an rails application with jquery UI.
I use draggable-droppable on a page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#listelement li").draggable({
    tolerance:"touch",
    cursor:"move",
    revert: "invalid"
  });
});
```

The problem is that it works only once I refresh the page, the first time it just won't be dragged...I used firebug on firefox to see there is a:

304 Not Modified 56ms

I understand it's not an error, rather an information telling me that the assets have not been reloaded.
However, it looks my problem comes from there, I just need a bit of direction...Would it be a good thing to reload the page in the controller on arrival?

Or maybe it can only come from my code?

If you have ever met that, how did you fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following gem into your gem file:

```
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

then do bundle and rails s

Comment: ok..is following lines available in your application.js           //= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.ui.draggable
//= require jquery.turbolinks  if not then add and bundle